# TypeScript installs incorrectly

Tags: syntax-highlighting, typescript

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express followed by the TypeScript plugin.

I launched VS and noticed that my .ts files are not getting any syntax highlighting.

I did not have any of the project templates relating to TypeScript, nor the Tools->Options->Text Editors->TypeScript settings.

I even tried to uninstall/re-install everything. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was desperately looking for a solution and it seems like none exist, so I decided to post the solution that worked for me.

It could be a complete fluke, but I thought I'd share it anyway, in case it can help someone else.

I have Windows 8 installed, but I don't think that's a factor since my other PC works just fine with Windows 8 + VS 2012 Express + TS plugin.

I went into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0` and with VS closed, I ran the `TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix` file.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You did find the appropriate work-around.

One known issue with the installer is that if your "documents" path is on a network share, the VSIX doesn't get installed automatically. Is that the case for you?

Comment: I used to have a junction set up to point my Documents => OneDrive\Documents. That's probably the same reason.