# TypeScript Syntax highlighting for VS 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, typescript

I have already created a Windows 8 App project supporting TypeScript compiling before starting the actual build process.

**But where's the syntax highlighting for the `*.ts` files?**

I have already installed the VS TypeScript extension, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you installing Visual Studio Express for Windows 8? This version is not yet supported by the TypeScript installer or the VSIX that ships with it.

Comment: Yes, I am. I'll get the Professional version in the next days, will this version support TypeScript syntax highlithing?

Comment: You were right, after installing VS 2012 Professional, the syntax highlighter worked perfectly! BTW did you only register on this site for answering my question?

Answer (score 2):

This should be working. If you go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates, do you see "TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio 2102" listed and enabled?

Comment: I don't see it, strange. Should I reinstall VS 2012? I have installed VS some weeks ago before Windows 8 came out.

Comment: See this poster's self-answer for a work-around (install the VSIX manually): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282564/typescript-installs-incorrectly

Comment: It doesn't work either after reinstalling VS 2012 for Windows 8 and the TypeScript extension. I don't see an entry in the tools list, too!